# NSubstitute ordered testing (Recived.InOrder) with return values for called methods results in CouldNotSetReturnDueToMissingInfoAboutLastCallException

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I used to write my tests with RhinoMocks and have switched to NSubstitute. 
Now I have a problem concerning ordered test. 
Lets say I have three small classes like

```
public interface IProvider
{
    int GetData();
}

public class Provider : IProvider
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    int Calculate(int data);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Calculate(int data)
    {
        if (data < 3)
        {
            return data;
        }

        return data * 2;
    }
}

public class Operator
{
    public void Operate(IProvider provider, ICalculator calculator)
    {
        int version = provider.GetData();

        this.Result = calculator.Calculate(version);
    }

    public int Result
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

When I write an ordered test using RhinoMocks, I can define the behaviour for the mocked classes like this:

```
[Test]
    public void RhinoMockOrderedTest()
    {
        var mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        var provider = mockRepository.DynamicMock<IProvider>();
        var calculator = mockRepository.DynamicMock<ICalculator>();

        using (mockRepository.Ordered())
        {
            provider.Expect(p => p.GetData()).Return(4);
            calculator.Expect(c => c.Calculate(4)).Return(9);
        }

        mockRepository.ReplayAll();

        var op = new Operator();
        op.Operate(provider, calculator);

        mockRepository.VerifyAll();

        Assert.That(op.Result, Is.EqualTo(9));
    }
```

Now I was trying to write an ordered test like the one above using NSubstitute, where I was also trying to check the call order and using defined return values:

```
[Test]
    public void NSubstituteOrderedTest()
    {
        var provider = Substitute.For<IProvider>();
        var calculator = Substitute.For<ICalculator>();

        var op = new Operator();
        op.Operate(provider, calculator);

        Received.InOrder(() =>
        {
            provider.GetData().Returns(4);
            calculator.Calculate(4).Returns(9);
        });

        Assert.That(op.Result, Is.EqualTo(9));
    }
```

Unfortunalely this does not work. It seems to me, when I try to use .Returns for a methon inside of the Received.InOrder - Action, it will alwys fail like this:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToMissingInfoAboutLastCallException
>   : Could not find information about the last call to return from.
>
> Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for
>   example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)), and that you are not
>   configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid
>   this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).
>
> If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that
>   the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return
>   values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.
>
> Correct use:  mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
>
> Potentially problematic use:
>     mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub()); Instead try:  var
>   returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();
>     mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

How can I write this test using NSubstitute ?

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSubstitute works differently to Rhino Mocks here -- it only supports Arrange-Act-Assert (AAA) style tests. This means we need to stub out calls we're interested in (arrange), run the code we want to test (act), then assert the results are as expected (assert).

[`Received.InOrder`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-in-order/) is only for assertions, and works like NSubstitute's [`Received()` method](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/) for each call. [`Returns`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value/) arranges for a call to return a particular result. NSubstitute does not allow us to mix the two. We can't do `sub.Received().Calculate().Returns(42)`, and it does not make sense to in AAA as there is little point in stubbing a return value after asserting we have already acted on the subject being tested and received all required calls.

Here is a passing version of the test from the question that separates the stubbing/arranging from the assertions:

```
[Test]
public void NSubstituteOrderedTest() {
    // Arrange
    var provider = Substitute.For<IProvider>();
    var calculator = Substitute.For<ICalculator>();

    provider.GetData().Returns(4);
    calculator.Calculate(4).Returns(9);

    // Act
    var op = new Operator();
    op.Operate(provider, calculator);

    // Assert
    Received.InOrder(() =>
    {
        provider.GetData();
        calculator.Calculate(4);
    });
    Assert.That(op.Result, Is.EqualTo(9));
}
```

---

*Aside: I know this is a simplified example, but I think it's worth noting that in many cases we can get away without testing the call ordering. For this simple case, we know `GetData()` is called first, as its value is passed to `Calculate()`, so the order is enforced via the data dependency. If the end result is correct, we know the call chain was correct. For more complicated cases we can use types for this (`Connect()` returns `ConnectedDb`, then `Query(ConnectedDb db)` ensures `Connect()` was called first.*

*Relying on knowledge of the implementation details of the code being tested (such as call ordering) can lead to brittle tests (i.e. they fail with small changes that should not affect the overall result), so it is best to avoid this where possible.*

*However, even with this disclaimer, it is sometimes useful to assert call order instead, so I hope this answer clears up this NSubstitute feature for you. :)*